# ECR list-images is not returning all the images

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I just pushed an image with the tag `v1.533.0` to my private repository in ECR. However, this version is not being listed when I call `list-images`.

The following command returns nothing:

```
aws ecr list-images --repository-name $MY_REPO --filter tagStatus=TAGGED --no-paginate --query 'reverse(sort_by(imageIds, &imageTag))[].imageTag' | grep v1.533.0
```

However, `describe-images` returns the image metadata for that tag:

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name $MY_REPO --image-ids "imageTag=v1.533.0"
{
    "imageDetails": [
        {
            "registryId": "",
            "repositoryName": "MY_REPO",
            "imageDigest": "sha256:000000000000000000",
            "imageTags": [
                "v1.533.0"
            ],
            "imageSizeInBytes": 90000000,
            "imagePushedAt": "2023-08-24T00:00:00+00:00",
            "imageManifestMediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
            "artifactMediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
            "lastRecordedPullTime": "2023-08-24T00:00:00+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I prevent that? Does ECR have a cache or something like that?

Comment: What is the output of `list-images` without `--query`?

Comment: What is the output of `aws ecr list-images --repository-name $MY_REPO` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifing the --max-items parameter to be a large number? Or check the output of the list-images command and see if you are getting a NextToken value? Wondering if all of the images aren't being returned for the first command. I've run into some AWS commands that have a default value of max-items; one I remember was defaulted to 20.